# Display local language for OSM data in TileMill

Tags: openstreetmap, labeling, tilemill

I'm following the instructions here to create a minimalist style map for Japan:

https://github.com/aaronlidman/Toner-for-Tilemill

Now, I've downloaded the OSM data, used *osm2pgsql*, created the tilemill project and it now properly displays in TileMill.

However, all the displayed city name labels are in the Romanized (english) characters.  Is there a way that I can get the Japanese (Kanji, hiragana, etc) displayed in place of thier romainzed dipictions? (*Street names do appear in the original Japanese, sometimes with Romanized letters in parens*)

I'm assuming that the original Japanese names are contained in the osm.pbf, but somewhere along the pipeline they are being ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand the default.style of osm2pgsql to import the local name as well.

The file is a simple text file, which you can edit with any text editor. You will find a line

```
node,way   name         text         linear
```

inside. This will import only the international readable name.
For local names, add

```
node,way   name:ja         text         linear
```

in a separate line.

You have to go through the tilemill style as well, look for the part where `name` or `name:en` is used, and replace it with something like

if exist `name:ja` then use `name:ja` else use `name`.

**EDIT**

Make sure TileMill is using your postgis database, and not the shapefiles that are in the `layers` folder. Those files do not have names with Japanese characters.

Comment: A note to anyone else running into the same problem.  In this case the Toner-for-Tilemill project uses pre-prepared labels that exist as shp files in the project.  These seem to be prepared for various zoom-levels using Dymo, read more about it here: http://www.nps.gov/npmap/blog/improving-park-label-placement-with-dymo-and-tilemill.html

Comment: Just to add: The standard Mapnik toolchain also uses prefabricated shapefiles for low zoom levels. This is much faster than querying the database for large areas.